# axios is not updating nor uninstalling

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

No matter how I try to update the axios package it just doesn't update t the last version. I'm running node server using **pm2**

I tried:

> `npm uninstall axios`

> `npm i axios`

or even

> ```
> npm update axios
> ```

but **axios** just remains the `"axios": "^0.21.1"`

How can I fix this?

Here is the dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    ...
  },
```

and here is the package-lock.json:

```
"packages": {
"dependencies": {
        "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        ...
```

after this we have another instances of axios inside packag.json:

```
"node_modules/axios": {
      "version": "0.21.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.21.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-dKQiRHxGD9PPRIUNIWvZhPTPpl1rf/OxTYKsqKUDjBwYylTvV7SjSHJb9ratfyzM6wCdLCOYLzs73qpg5c4iGA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "follow-redirects": "^1.10.0"
      }
    },

"axios": {
      "version": "0.21.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.21.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-dKQiRHxGD9PPRIUNIWvZhPTPpl1rf/OxTYKsqKUDjBwYylTvV7SjSHJb9ratfyzM6wCdLCOYLzs73qpg5c4iGA==",
      "requires": {
        "follow-redirects": "^1.10.0"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` folder and `.lock` file then installing again and delete this `"axios": "^0.21.1",` line from package.json file before installing.

Comment: Delete the node_modules and the package-lock.json. Then repeat the commands that you already used.

Comment: You are in the wrong directory probably

Comment: You can try npm install axios@^1, you have perhaps a conflict with another package that prevent the update

Comment: npm install axios@^1 not working..

Comment: Can I copy and paste a new version of axios in axios folder inside node_modules ?

Comment: Just edit your `package.json` file, set the Axios version to `^1.2.1` and run `npm install`. Alternately, try out [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) (NodeJS) or [ky](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky) (browser); Axios has been really unstable lately and I cannot recommend it at all

Comment: `npm install axios@latest` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the package.json file set Axios to the version you would like such as `"axios": "^1.2.1"`. Then run `npm install`.

If that doesn't work, remove the package-lock.json file & the node_modules directory and try `npm install` again.